# math mode align expressions too far apart

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I am attempting to allow following expressions in math mode:

```
\begin{flalign*}
  \Gamma_1 ; x : T ; \Gamma_2 \vdash{}& x
  &&\Rightarrow T & \\
  \Gamma \vdash&{} \lambda(z : T).t
  &&\Rightarrow \forall(z : T) U, & \\
\end{flalign*}
```

It produces text similar to following:

```
Γ 1 ; x ∶ T ; Γ 2 ⊢ x                   ⇒ T
                Γ ⊢λ(z ∶ T ).t          ⇒ ∀(z ∶ T )U,
```

My problem with it, is the `\Rightarrow` is too far apart from whatever expression that comes after `\vdash` immediately.

I wish I can produce following results as alignment:

```
Γ 1 ; x ∶ T ; Γ 2 ⊢ x           ⇒ T
                Γ ⊢ λ(z ∶ T ).t ⇒ ∀(z ∶ T )U,
```

Note that, the `\Rightarrow` only goes as far as it needed, not far apart to form a separate column. Searching around the internet, there are examples aligning pushing to left by adding a trailing `&`, but for some reason it does not work in my case. How would you solve this problem?

Comment: Why using `flalign` to begin with? Its name means “**full length align**”, not “flush left align”.

Comment: @egreg i honestly don't know. I use `align*` before but i saw a few answers use `flalign*`.

Comment: It'e used mainly when you have three alignment groups  one flush left, the second in the middle column and the last flushright. You should take a look at the documentation of amsmath.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this? I took the liberty to replace the `.` (in the second line) with a `\cdot` which I thought more appropriate:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\begin{document}

Some text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text.
\begin{fleqn}[\parindent]
\begin{alignat*}{2}
    \Gamma_1 ; x : T ; \Gamma_2 & \vdash{} x
  &&\Rightarrow T \\
  \Gamma & \vdash \lambda(z : T)\cdot t
  &&\Rightarrow \forall(z : T) U,
   \end{alignat*}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you. now i recall i saw `alignat` before. surprised that I didn't manage to google it out.